# Qt-creator wont show locals or expressions on Android

Tags: android, qt, gdb, qt-creator

I recently started working from a fresh system and now I am unable to get any locals or expressions when debugging on Android. The debugger is able to reach breakpoints but the  locals window is empty. [image]

I've tried on different, simpler projects and the issue still persists.

I'm using qt-5.0.1, qt-creator 2.8.0, gcc 4.8, ndkr9 and its included gdb (7.3.1-gg2)

My debugger output is here: http://pastebin.com/mQFcDwed

Does anyone know how to fix this? I read that it could have to do with the gdb version but I don't know if I can change that without upgrading the ndk (its the most recent)

Answer (score 0):

I had absolutely the same problem and the solution was very simple.

Actually the part that causes that issue is ndk-r9. I've switched to the previous version and now everything is OK. My current NDK version is r8e